# Julia Redis key expiration callback function

Tags: redis, julia

I am using Redis.jl and I need to define a callback function for key expiration. I checked its Pub/Sub documentation but did not find any help about **__keyevent@0__:expired**. Could anyone help please?

**Update 1:**
for channel **__keyevent@15__:expired** and callback function **f(chan, key)** I got this Error:
MethodError(Redis.SubscriptionMessage, ("OK",), 0x0000000000006a57)